# Making a Calendar for TUG

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, fun

This question is triggered by a post from Peter Wilson in [comp.text.tex`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.text.tex).

Peter wrote: *TUG members produced a calendar for 2012 and, if I remember correctly, for some previous years as well. I really hope that there will there be one for 2013.*

FYI The calendar should be generated with LaTeX and friends, including LaTeX-generated pictures.

My question is how do we do this in LaTeX?

The following is an example of the [2009 calendar](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2009/feb/06/tex-calendar/).

[image: 2009 calendar]
<sub>(source: [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/media/weblog/tex-calendar/calendar.jpg))</sub>  .

Comment: [TeXample](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/nontech/calendars/) has a few examples

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks. I knew about them. I was referring to examples of previous TUG calendars.

Comment: Well, since they are at least in some way related I thought it wouldn't hurt mentioning them here... :)

Comment: @cgnieder Sure. As it turned out I also found an example on [_TeXample_](http://texample.net).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, this is not exactly what you want, but I was thinking about asking for calendars a few weeks ago in order to make it a Community Wiki, but finally I didn't. However, I post here my solution (which is far far away from being optimal, I encourage all of you to make it better —but, of course, without changing the appearance–). I repeat, may be it's not what you want.

The file is this:

```
\documentclass[border=4.9mm, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% MCAL -------------------------------
\usepackage{mcal}
% MCAL -------------------------------

\begin{document}\estilodetexto% To set up \sffamily, \bfseries…
\thisyear{2013}% The year the calendar is about.
\colordelosfestivos{red}% The color of holidays.
\remaincolor{white}% The color under the top rectangle (where the title and the previous and next calendar are)
\resubcolor{white}% The color under the names of the week
\mooncounter=2% To set the first moon of the year (0,1,2,3)
\enero[7,14,21,28]{7}% The months …
\febrero[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\marzo[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\abril[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\mayo[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\junio[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\julio[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\agosto[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\septiembre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\octubre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\noviembre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\diciembre[4,12,19,27]{6,8,25,31}
\end{document}
```

It uses a custom `mcal.sty` which I include later. The usage is easy, each month (now it's in spanish, but you get an idea) takes a mandatory argument, the days of the month which are holidays, separated by commas, and a optional argument, the days of the month with the moon phase.

[image]

You can see how it fully looks [here](http://f.cl.ly/items/3G1G3D1U161D1X2g2X3Q/Calendario.pdf).

Apart from that, the `mcal.sty` has this content:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\def\estilodetexto{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Year}{2013}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{12}% Diciembre
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\oldYear}{\Year-1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newYear}{\Year+1}%
\def\colorfestivos{red}
\def\maincolor{white}
\def\subcolor{white}

\def\remaincolor#1{%
\let\maincolor\relax%
\def\maincolor{#1}%
}

\def\resubcolor#1{%
\let\subcolor\relax%
\def\subcolor{#1}%
}

\def\colordelosfestivos#1{%
\let\colorfestivos\relax%
\def\colorfestivos{#1}%
}

\def\thisyear#1{%
\let\Year\relax%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Year}{#1}%
}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{mathabx}

\newcommand*{\listadefestivos}[1]{%
    \def\festivos{}%
    \foreach \f in {#1} {%
        \xappto\festivos{if (day of month = \f) [\colorfestivos]}}%
}

\newcount\mooncounter
\def\moonreset{\global\mooncounter=-1\relax}
\moonreset

\def\moon{%
    \global\advance\mooncounter by 1\relax%
    \ifcase\mooncounter $\newmoon$%
        \or $\rightmoon$%
        \or $\fullmoon$%
        \or $\leftmoon$\global\mooncounter=-1\relax%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand*{\listadelunas}[1]{%
    \def\lunas{}%
    \foreach \l in {#1} {%
        \xappto\lunas{if (day of month = \l) [day text=\noexpand\moon\%d-]}
    }%
}

\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
        \foreach \d/\l in {0/L,1/M,2/X,3/J,4/V,5/S,6/D}{
            \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
            \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
            \node[every day,day heading]{\estilodetexto\Large\l};%
            } 
        }{}%
    }%
]
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\def\Month{%
\ifnum\monthcounter=1%
    Enero\else
    \ifnum\monthcounter=2% 
        Febrero\else
        \ifnum\monthcounter=3% 
            Marzo\else
            \ifnum\monthcounter=4% 
                Abril\else
                \ifnum\monthcounter=5% 
                    Mayo\else
                    \ifnum\monthcounter=6% 
                        Junio\else
                        \ifnum\monthcounter=7% 
                            Julio\else
                            \ifnum\monthcounter=8% 
                                Agosto\else
                                \ifnum\monthcounter=9% 
                                    Septiembre\else
                                    \ifnum\monthcounter=10% 
                                        Octubre\else
                                        \ifnum\monthcounter=11% 
                                            Noviembre\else
                                            \ifnum\monthcounter=12% 
                                                Diciembre%
                                            \fi%
                                        \fi%
                                    \fi%
                                \fi%
                            \fi%
                        \fi%
                    \fi%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
\fi%
}

\def\findemes{\ifnum\monthcounter=12%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{1} \else%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{\monthcounter+1}%
\fi%
}

\def\nuevapagina{\findemes%
%\newpage%
}

\newcommand\mes[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
% Cuadrícula
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
        \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Lunes/2,Martes/6,Miércoles/10,Jueves/14,Viernes/18,Sábado/22,Domingo/26}{%
        \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
        }%
% Calendario mes anterior       
        \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\Year-12-01 to \Year-12-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

        \findemes%
% CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
        \listadelunas{#1}%
        \listadefestivos{#2}%
        \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
            week list,%
            day xshift = 4cm,%
            day yshift = 2.5cm,%
            if = {(Sunday) [\colorfestivos]},%
            ] at (4,14.3) \festivos \lunas;%

        \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} de \Year};%

        \findemes%
% Calendario mes siguiente
        \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\nuevapagina
}

\newcommand\enero[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
% Cuadrícula
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
        \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Lunes/2,Martes/6,Miércoles/10,Jueves/14,Viernes/18,Sábado/22,Domingo/26}{%
        \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
        }%
% Calendario mes anterior       
        \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\oldYear-12-01 to \oldYear-12-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

        \findemes%
% CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
        \listadelunas{#1}%
        \listadefestivos{#2}%
        \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
            week list,%
            day xshift = 4cm,%
            day yshift = 2.5cm,%
            if = {(Sunday) [\colorfestivos]},%
            ] at (4,14.3) \festivos \lunas;%

        \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} de \Year};%

        \findemes%
% Calendario mes siguiente
        \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\nuevapagina
}

\let\febrero\mes%
\let\marzo\mes%
\let\abril\mes%
\let\mayo\mes%
\let\junio\mes%
\let\julio\mes%
\let\agosto\mes%
\let\septiembre\mes%
\let\octubre\mes%
\let\noviembre\mes%

\newcommand\diciembre[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}%
% Cuadrícula
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
        \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
        \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
        \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Lunes/2,Martes/6,Miércoles/10,Jueves/14,Viernes/18,Sábado/22,Domingo/26}{%
        \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
        }%
% Calendario mes anterior       
        \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\Year-12-01 to \Year-12-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

        \findemes%
% CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
        \listadelunas{#1}%
        \listadefestivos{#2}%
        \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
            week list,%
            day xshift = 4cm,%
            day yshift = 2.5cm,%
            if = {(Sunday) [\colorfestivos]},%
            ] at (4,14.3) \festivos \lunas;%

        \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} de \Year};%

        \findemes%
% Calendario mes siguiente
        \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
        \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\newYear-\monthcounter-1 to \newYear-\monthcounter-last,%
            day xshift=1em,%
            day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
            day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
            week list,%
            day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\nuevapagina
}
```

As you can see, it is very basic and uses `tikz`'s `calendar` library.

**EDIT:** It's in spanish (+ a bit of english, it was done fast and without thinking so much, you will se a lot of randomness inside :P). I will try to translate it into english in the future.

Comment: Looks nice. Thanks. Your sources should make life much easier for others.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thank you! It was done to make the life easier to my mother, which annually makes the calendar for the whole family.

Answer (score 22):

I wrote one for 2012... but i was lacking material for 2013 since i was writing my thesis in the past months. http://www.disk0s1.de/posts/latex/texianischer-kalender/

I basically used the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\mymo}[3]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \centering%
        \noindent\Huge\pgfcalendarmonthname{\value{tgmymo}}\normalsize\stepcounter{tgmymo}\\[1cm]%
        #3
    \end{minipage}\vfill\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture} \pgfcalendar{cal}{#1}{#2}{%
        \ifdate{workday}%
        {\tikzset{filling/.style={fill=black!05}}}%
        {\tikzset{filling/.style={fill=orange!20}}}
        %%
        \def\normal{\node (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname) at (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday*2.5,0) [filling,  rectangle,rounded corners, text width=.1\textwidth,text height=.8cm ,align=right] {\\$\pgfcalendarcurrentday$};}%
        %%
        \ifdate{equals=2013-01-10}{\node (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname) at (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday*2.5,0) [filling,  rectangle,rounded corners, text width=.1\textwidth ,text height=.8cm ,align=right,] {{\small D.  E. Knuth}\\$\pgfcalendarcurrentday$};}{\normal}%
        \ifdate{equals=2013-02-07}{\node (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname) at (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday*2.5,0) [filling,  rectangle,rounded corners, text width=.1\textwidth ,text height=.8cm ,align=right,] {{\small L. Lamport}\\$\pgfcalendarcurrentday$};}{}%
        \ifdate{equals=2013-05-05}{\node (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname) at (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday*2.5,0) [filling,  rectangle,rounded corners, text width=.1\textwidth ,text height=.8cm ,align=right,] {{\small Julia}\\$\pgfcalendarcurrentday$};}{}%
        %
        \ifdate{equals=2013-08-01}{\node (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname) at (\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday*2.5,0) [filling,  rectangle,rounded corners, text width=.1\textwidth ,text height=.8cm ,align=right,] {{\small Tobias}\\$\pgfcalendarcurrentday$};}{}%
        %
        \ifdate{Sunday}{\pgftransformyshift{-4.2em}}{}%
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}\end{minipage}\clearpage}
```

This sets the page with the calender, the content (picture etc.) shall be invoked as argument #3. Like this: `\mymo{2013-01-01}{2013-01-last}{\input{jan.tex}}`.

[image]

It was printed on 100g/m^2 DIN A4 paper with a high res laser printer and shipped to some of my friends.

Comment: Thanks. Look nice. Perhaps stealing a few ideas from [_TeXample_](http://texample.net/) could turn this into a full-blown calendar.

Comment: like having Mo/Tu/... on the column headers or so? The appearance is exactly what i wanted a year ago... So i'm not quite familiar with the definition of a full-blown calendar. As i did for some birthdays any single date event can be set with `pgf` in case you want puplic holiday etc.