# Translating a package

Tags: packages

I am translating a calendar package (mcal.sty) from Portuguese into Indonesian, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/making-a-calendar-for-tug/91604#91604).

```
\documentclass[border=4.9mm, bahasa, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
\title{2014}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Enero}{Januari}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Febrero}{Februari}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Marzo}{Maret}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Abril}{April}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Mayo}{Mei}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Junio}{Juni}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Julio}{Juli}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Agosto}{Agustus}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Septiembre}{September}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Octubre}{Oktober}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Noviembre}{November}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Diciembre}{Desember}

\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Lunes}{Senin}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Martes}{Selasa}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Miércoles}{Rabu}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Jueves}{Kamis}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Viernes}{Jumat}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Sábado}{Sabtu}
\deftranslation[to=bahasa]{Domingo}{Minggu}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bahasa}{translator}

\usepackage{mcal}

\begin{document}
\estilodetexto% To set up \sffamily, \bfseries…
\thisyear{2014}% The year the calendar is about.
\colordelosfestivos{red}% The color of holidays.
\remaincolor{white}% The color under the top rectangle (where the title and the previous and next calendar are)
\resubcolor{white}% The color under the names of the week
\mooncounter=2% To set the first moon of the year (0,1,2,3)
\enero[7,14,21,28]{7}% The months …
\febrero[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\marzo[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\abril[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\mayo[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\junio[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\julio[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\agosto[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\septiembre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\octubre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\noviembre[7,14,21,28]{1,2,3,7,9,25}
\diciembre[4,12,19,27]{6,8,25,31}

\end{document}
```

What is wrong? Please show me the correct codes and results.

Comment: What does it produce when compiled?

Comment: It is in Portuguese.

Comment: Why does it produce an output in Portuguese rather than errors?

Comment: If `mcal` is the code from [Making a Calendar for TUG](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91604/5049) then as far as I can see the month names are hard-coded. You don't need the `translator` package but change the month names in your `mcal.sty` directly (see the lines after `\def\Month{%`)

Comment: @cgnieder: Thank you, now this problem has been solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mcal` is the code from [Making a Calendar for TUG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91604/5049) then as far as I can see the month names are hard-coded. You don't need the `translator` package but change the month names in your `mcal.sty` directly, see the lines after `\def\Month{%`:

```
\def\Month{%
\ifnum\monthcounter=1
    Enero\else
    \ifnum\monthcounter=2 
        Febrero\else
        \ifnum\monthcounter=3 
            Marzo\else
            \ifnum\monthcounter=4 
                Abril\else
                \ifnum\monthcounter=5 
                    Mayo\else
                    \ifnum\monthcounter=6 
                        Junio\else
                        \ifnum\monthcounter=7 
                            Julio\else
                            \ifnum\monthcounter=8 
                                Agosto\else
                                \ifnum\monthcounter=9 
                                    Septiembre\else
                                    \ifnum\monthcounter=10 
                                        Octubre\else
                                        \ifnum\monthcounter=11 
                                            Noviembre\else
                                            \ifnum\monthcounter=12 
                                                Diciembre%
                                            \fi
                                        \fi
                                    \fi
                                \fi
                            \fi
                        \fi
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
}
```