# Tikz calendar font size problem

Tags: tikz-calendar

I adapted the calendar as shown in: [Making a Calendar for TUG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/making-a-calendar-for-tug/) into my own version. But I cannot achieve to get the dates with the moon phases (variable "lunas" in mcal.sty) in the "Huge" text format. Thanks for your help.

main.tex:

```
    \documentclass[border=4.9mm, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    % MCAL -------------------------------
    \usepackage{mcal}
    % MCAL -------------------------------

    \begin{document}\estilodetexto% To set up \sffamily, \bfseries etc.
    \thisyear{2019}% The year the calendar is about.
    \colorofHolidays{red}% The color of holidays.
    \colorofWeekend{gray}% The color of weekend days.
    \remaincolor{white}% The color under the top rectangle (where the title and the previous and next calendar are)
    \resubcolor{white}% The color under the names of the week
    \mooncounter=-1% To set the first moon of the year (0=Right Moon,1=Full Moon,2=Left Moon,-1=New Moon)
    \januari[6,14,21,27]{1}% moon dates (see: https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/) and holiday dates for this month
    \februari[4,12,19,26]{}
    \maart[6,14,21,28]{}
    \april[5,12,19,27]{21,22}
    \mei[5,12,18,26]{1,30}
    \juni[3,10,17,25]{9,10}
    \juli[2,9,16,25]{21}
    \augustus[1,7,15,23,30]{15}
    \september[6,14,22,28]{}
    \oktober[5,13,21,28]{}
    \november[4,12,19,26]{1,11}
    \december[4,12,19,26]{25}
    \end{document}
```

mcal.sty:

```
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}
    \RequirePackage{xcolor}

    \def\estilodetexto{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Year}{2019}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{12}% December
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\oldYear}{\Year-1}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newYear}{\Year+1}%
    \def\colorofHolidays{red}
    \def\colorofWeekend{gray}
    \def\maincolor{white}
    \def\subcolor{white}

    \def\remaincolor#1{%
    \let\maincolor\relax%
    \def\maincolor{#1}%
    }

    \def\resubcolor#1{%
    \let\subcolor\relax%
    \def\subcolor{#1}%
    }

    \def\colorofHolidays#1{%
    \let\colorHolidays\relax%
    \def\colorHolidays{#1}%
    }

    \def\colorofWeekend#1{%
    \let\colorWeekend\relax%
    \def\colorWeekend{#1}%
    }

    \def\thisyear#1{%
    \let\Year\relax%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Year}{#1}%
    }

    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \RequirePackage{mathabx}

    \newcommand*{\listadefestivos}[1]{%
        \def\festivos{}%
        \foreach \f in {#1} {%
            \xappto\festivos{if (day of month = \f) [\colorHolidays]}}%
    }

    \newcount\mooncounter
    \def\moonreset{\global\mooncounter=-1\relax}
    \moonreset

    \def\moon{%
        \global\advance\mooncounter by 1\relax%
        \ifcase\mooncounter $\newmoon$%
            \or $\rightmoon$%
            \or $\fullmoon$%
            \or $\leftmoon$\global\mooncounter=-1\relax%
        \fi%
    }

    \newcommand*{\listadelunas}[1]{%
        \def\lunas{}%
        \foreach \l in {#1} {%
            \xappto\lunas{if (day of month = \l) [day text=\noexpand\moon\%d-]}
        }%
    }

    \makeatletter%
    \tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
    \tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
    \tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
        execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
            \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
            \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
            \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/D,2/W,3/D,4/V,5/Z,6/Z}{
                \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
                \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
                \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
                \node[every day,day heading]{\estilodetexto\normalsize\l};%
                } 
            }{}%
        }%
    ]
    \makeatother

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \def\Month{%
    \ifnum\monthcounter=1%
        Januari\else
        \ifnum\monthcounter=2% 
            Februari\else
            \ifnum\monthcounter=3% 
                Maart\else
                \ifnum\monthcounter=4% 
                    April\else
                    \ifnum\monthcounter=5% 
                        Mei\else
                        \ifnum\monthcounter=6% 
                            Juni\else
                            \ifnum\monthcounter=7% 
                                Juli\else
                                \ifnum\monthcounter=8% 
                                    Augustus\else
                                    \ifnum\monthcounter=9% 
                                        September\else
                                        \ifnum\monthcounter=10% 
                                            Oktober\else
                                            \ifnum\monthcounter=11% 
                                                November\else
                                                \ifnum\monthcounter=12% 
                                                    December%
                                                \fi%
                                            \fi%
                                        \fi%
                                    \fi%
                                \fi%
                            \fi%
                        \fi%
                    \fi%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    }

    \def\findemes{\ifnum\monthcounter=12%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{1} \else%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\monthcounter}{\monthcounter+1}%
    \fi%
    }

    \def\nuevapagina{\findemes%
    %\newpage%
    }

    \newcommand\mes[2][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    % Cuadricula
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
            \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Maandag/2,Dinsdag/6,Woensdag/10,Donderdag/14,Vrijdag/18,Zaterdag/22,Zondag/26}{%
            \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
            }%
    % Calendario mes anterior       
            \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-01 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

            \findemes%
    % CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
            \listadelunas{#1}%
            \listadefestivos{#2}%
            \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                week list,%
                day xshift = 4cm,%
                day yshift = 2.5cm,%
                day text=\Huge \%d-,%
                if = {(Saturday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                if = {(Sunday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                ] at (2.7,13.4) \festivos \lunas;%

            \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} \Year};%

            \findemes%
    % Calendario mes siguiente
            \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \nuevapagina
    }

    \newcommand\januari[2][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    % CuadrÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â­cula
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
            \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Maandag/2,Dinsdag/6,Woensdag/10,Donderdag/14,Vrijdag/18,Zaterdag/22,Zondag/26}{%
            \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
            }%
    % Calendario mes anterior       
            \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\oldYear-12-01 to \oldYear-12-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

            \findemes%
    % CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
            \listadelunas{#1}%
            \listadefestivos{#2}%
            \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                week list,%
                day xshift = 4cm,%
                day yshift = 2.5cm,%
                day text=\Huge \%d-,%
                if = {(Saturday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                if = {(Sunday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                ] at (2.7,13.4) \festivos \lunas;%

            \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} \Year};%

            \findemes%
    % Calendario mes siguiente
            \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \nuevapagina
    }

    \let\februari\mes%
    \let\maart\mes%
    \let\april\mes%
    \let\mei\mes%
    \let\juni\mes%
    \let\juli\mes%
    \let\augustus\mes%
    \let\september\mes%
    \let\oktober\mes%
    \let\november\mes%

    \newcommand\december[2][]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    % Cuadricula
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\maincolor] (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[fill opacity=1,fill=\subcolor] (0,15) rectangle (28,16);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=2.5cm] (0,0) grid (28,15);%
            \draw[xstep=4cm, ystep=1cm] (0,15) grid (28,16);%
            \draw (0,20) rectangle (28,16);%
            \foreach \dia/\posicion in {Maandag/2,Dinsdag/6,Woensdag/10,Donderdag/14,Vrijdag/18,Zaterdag/22,Zondag/26}{%
            \node (\dia) at (\posicion,15.5) {\dia};%
            }%
    % Calendario mes anterior       
            \node (titulocalanterior) at (2.75,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calanterior) [dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (1.2,18.7);%

            \findemes%
    % CALENDARIO PRINCIPAL
            \listadelunas{#1}%
            \listadefestivos{#2}%
            \calendar[dates=\Year-\monthcounter-1 to \Year-\monthcounter-last,%
                week list,%
                day xshift = 4cm,%
                day yshift = 2.5cm,%
                day text=\Huge \%d-,%
                if = {(Saturday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                if = {(Sunday) [\colorWeekend]},%
                ] at (2.7,13.4) \festivos \lunas;%

            \node[scale=2] (Mtitle) at (14,18) {\Huge \Month{} \Year};%

            \findemes%
    % Calendario mes siguiente
            \node (titulocalsiguiente) at (25.05,19.5) {\Month};%
            \calendar (calsiguiente) [dates=\newYear-\monthcounter-1 to \newYear-\monthcounter-last,%
                day xshift=1em,%
                day yshift = 1em-1ex,%
                day text=\normalsize \%d-,%
                week list,%
                day letter headings] at (23.5,18.7);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \nuevapagina
    }
```

[image: example for January 2019:]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I get an error when I try to compile your files: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.15     \resubcolor`. Please make your example compilable (there are other errors as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code in this part of `mcal.sty`:

```
\def\moon{%
    \global\advance\mooncounter by 1\relax%
    \ifcase\mooncounter $\newmoon$%
        \or $\rightmoon$%
        \or $\fullmoon$%
        \or $\leftmoon$\global\mooncounter=-1\relax%
    \fi%
}
```

to the following:

```
\def\moon{%
    \global\advance\mooncounter by 1\relax%
    \ifcase\mooncounter \Huge $\newmoon$% <- Add `\Huge'
        \or \Huge $\rightmoon$% <- Add `\Huge'
        \or \Huge $\fullmoon$% <- Add `\Huge'
        \or \Huge $\leftmoon$\global\mooncounter=-1\relax% <- Add `\Huge'
    \fi%
}
```